# How do I print list of things in one line with a listing style (square, circle, etc.) in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to print couple of things as in a list in HTML. I tried couple of things but none worked! Let's say I have a list of (Red, Green, Yellow, Black, Blue, and Purple), and I used ul and li to list them such as:

- Red.

  Green.

  Yellow.

  Black.

  Blue.

  Purple.

But I want to print the list to look like:

```
- Red.           - Green.          - Yellow.
- Black.         - Blue.           - Purple.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`list-style-type` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) can be used for changing the bullet type. As for printing the items in rows, you can use [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) and [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float);

```css
li {
  list-style-type: square;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

li.row-start {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item one</li>
  <li>Item two</li>
  <li>Item three</li>
  <li class="row-start">Item four</li>
  <li>Item five</li>
  <li>Item six</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It still gonna print each element in a new line. What I want is to print like 3 elements in a line and then the other 3 in another line.

Comment: Yeap, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!